# apscheduler start func

Tags: python, apscheduler

мне нужно запускать функцию ровно в '1 min', '5 min', '15 min', '30 min', '1 hour', '4 hours', '8 hours', '12 hours', '1 day', '3 days', '1 week', '1 month'

т.е в 0.01 итд для 1 мин

для 5 мин 0.05, 00.10 соотвевственно

как я могу это сделать с from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

Comment: для месяца/недели в 00.00 начала каждого

Comment: а в чем проблема?